# How to build a Google-chrome tabs and menubar interface in Java Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, open-source, google-chrome

Does someone know an open source project or code snippets, which demonstrate how to create a google-chrome like interface with similar tabs and toolbar in Swing?

I know, that I can use [JTabbedPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html), but I'm thinking of an interface which looks and feels very similar to the google chrome "tabbed browsing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just created my own open-source library for this, called Jhrome.  Check it out!

It's available on github: https://github.com/jedwards1211/Jhrome

Documentation is sparse right now, but it's pretty solid, except for AWT/Swing memory leaks I haven't figured out yet.  If enough people are interested in it I'll polish it up.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably pull it off with an undecorated JFrame (setUndecorated(true)) to get rid of the title bar.

You'd then create a layout with a tabbed pane filling the window and then overlay the min/max/close buttons on the top right.

If tabbed pane is too inflexible, you will need to put a button bar across the top, with toggle buttons controlling multiple content panels, and do the tab look yourself; as each button becomes active it hides the current panel and unhides the panel that belongs to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should opt to [Substance LAF](https://substance.dev.java.net/) and make a Chrome-lookalike skin for it *(Substance is a skinnable LAF which sort of extends Swing's functionality on the graphical side)* and use that, won't be the easiest way to do it but if you have the time and willpower, you'll get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question (and its answers) too: [JTabbedPane: Components before and after the tabs themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888856/jtabbedpane-components-before-and-after-the-tabs-themselves/891862).