# JTabbedPane: Components before and after the tabs themselves

Tags: java, user-interface, google-chrome, jtabbedpane

This is similar to the question [How to build a Google-chrome tabs and menubar interface in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464149/how-to-build-a-google-chrome-tabs-and-menubar-interface-in-java-swing) (I want to accomplish the same), but more to the point: How do I put components in front and behind the tabs in a JTabbedPane?

I've already come up with the buttons-idea myself, but I'd rather have a JTabbedPane, since that is really what it is, but decorated with a button or icons on the sides.

I've seen that the [laf-widget](https://laf-widget.dev.java.net/) project from Kirill does something like it (the magnifying-glass icon to the left of the tabs) for several LaFs. However, I must admit that I'm not yet well enough versed to understand how he does it - and also it seems like a somewhat complicated process, whereby one "physically" change the LaF in question (bytecode manipulates it), injecting the laf-widget stuff into the UI delegates - and I still don't know how the JTabbedPane or TabbedPaneUI is actually modulated to inject that icon/button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally asked Kirill of [Substance LaF](https://substance.dev.java.net/see.html)/laf-widget of how he manages to put a button in front of the tabs in the laf-widget that decorates JTabbedPanes, and this is his reply:

> It relies on the
>   BasicTabbedPaneUI.tabAreaInsets field
>   to make room for the button, and
>   custom setBounds of the button
>   component to position itself in that
>   area.
>
> For more code, see TabOverviewButton
>   and TabOverviewDialogWidget classes in
>   the laf-widget project.
>
> In general, the tabbed pane UI
>   delegate is one of the least
>   attractive ones to enhance since it
>   has a lot of private and package
>   protected methods

Thanks, Kirill!

Answer (score 1):

[JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/) have a tabbed pane as part of their component suite that exposes this functionality as simple setBeforeComponent() and setAfterComponent() methods.

There's a demo of it in here: http://www.jidesoft.com/products/1.4/jide_demo.jnlp

Comment: It has?! Awesome - I just got pointed in the direction of Jide from another answer here on Stackoverflow, but hadn't gotten to check out the APIs yet - the screenshots doesn't hint towards such a feature at all. I guess one looses the LaF using Jide?

Comment: It depends what you're doing. The JIDE components are pretty good about honouring LaFs. We use it with synthetica and it's seamless.

Comment: How does it depend? Do you have a pointer for where some documentation resides? I can't seem to find it. I try using it with Substance now, and it blatanly doesn't honor that. It seems to use some "vsnet" UI stuff of its own to paint.